# The django login screen does not transition from loading to page

Tags: django, postgresql

I changed the database to postgresql with django.
And after migrete, I can't log in when I check my login screen.
I also tried to log in to the management screen, but I could not log in.
Both have stopped during loading.
The user is created by executing createsuperuser.
And the user was created when checking the database.
I deleted the migrete file or restarted the server, but it doesn't work.
If you enter the wrong password, "Your username and password didn't match. Please try again."
There is no display of errors, etc., and the server is loading even after stopping.

I also did the following command

```
find . -path "*/migrations/*.py" -not -name "__init__.py" -delete
find . -path "*/migrations/*.pyc"  -delete
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

If you enter an incorrect password after restarting the server, the message “Please enter the correct username and password for the staff account. Both fields are case sensitive.”
This is done in an anaconda virtual environment.

psql (PostgreSQL) 11.5
Python 3.7.4
django2.2.4

It was impossible to build a new virtual environment and move only the code.

Comment: Can you start a Django shell `python manage.py shell` and then run `from django.contrib.auth.models import User; print(User.objects.all())`? Does your user get printed?

Comment: superuser
print is done.

Comment: How are you running your server? Do you have the environment variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` set to something different in your shell to when you run the site?

Comment: It is running with python manage.py runserver.
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is start_app_name.setting.

Answer (score 0):

It was done after restarting the PC.